# adding the same normal distribution together

Tags: probability, statistics

I've got a fairly beginner probability question that goes like "A portfolio consists of
9 independent stocks, each of which is normally distributed with an average return of \$0.15 and a standard deviation of \$0.40. What is the average return and standard deviation of the entire portfolio?"
I define a the normal distribution like

```
mu = .15
sigma = .4
f = lambda x:  1/np.sqrt(2*sigma**2*np.pi)*np.exp(-(x - mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
```

And I can verify the mean $\mu$ with $E[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}xf_X(x)dx$ like this:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
quad(lambda x: x*f(x), -np.inf, np.inf)
```

which returns .15 as expected. Then to answer the question about the mean of the combined 9 independent stocks, I do

```
quad(lambda x: x*9*f(x), -np.inf, np.inf)
```

and I get the right answer which is just $9\mu=.135$. For the standard deviation $\sigma$ of the combined 9 independent stocks, I'm aware that
$$\sigma = \sqrt{\text{Var}[X]}$$
$$\text{Var}[X] = \int_{x}^{}(x-E[X])^2\cdot f_{X}(x)dx$$
$$\text{Var}[X] = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$$
$$E[X^2]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}x^2f_{X}(x)dx$$
Using the the first two expressions like

```
np.sqrt( quad(lambda x: (x-1.35)**2*f(x), -np.inf, np.inf)[0])
```

I get an answer of 1.26, which is close to the advertised solution of 1.2. If I use the third expression, like $\text{Var}[9X] = E[(9X)^2]-(E[9X])^2$ in code as as

```
a = quad(lambda x: (9*x)**2*f(x)  , -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
b = quad(lambda x: x*9*f(x) , -np.inf, np.inf)[0]**2
np.sqrt(a - b)
```

I get 3.6, and curiously, $3.6/3=1.2$. I see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) that means and variances are additive, but the proofs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) are over my head. How are my solution attempts incorrectly coded? What is the correct way of doing this without the knowledge that the means and variances are just additive?

Comment: It might be helpful to have a look at any introduction to statistics book.

Comment: First expression is bad since $f$ is center at $.15$, which you’re subtracting 1.35 from, so you’re getting the mean square distance from 1.35 to something centered at .15, so you’re getting something more than 1.2. 

You’re $f$ is wrong in the first place because sigma represents standard deviation, so you’re squaring an extra time.

Comment: I see that I messed up the distribution function $f$, and I fixed that, and adjusted the numbers. I'm still curious why I can't do this out in such a manner. Does it require a simulation if I didn't know the means and variances are just additive? I'm most unsure about the $E[X^2]$ calculation for all 9 stocks.

Comment: I was able to find the correct result empirically with a simulation that adds element-wise the samples of each individual distribution.